# Using jQuery(function($) multiple times

Tags: jquery

I'm just learning jQuery, and discovered the nice `jQuery(function($)` shorthand for document ready (described [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3)).

My question: Is it possible to use this syntax multiple times in different files that are all downloaded to the browser from the same page? (I don't need to call variables from file A in file B)

Comment: Yes you can, but why not just test it?

Comment: Just because I'm in the middle of a Code School course and am trying not to branch out too much (focusing on the course and its included exercises). Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes u can....all will get executed On first Called first run basis....

Comment: I definitely didn't downvote this. Going to accept this answer.